# Save output of DSolve as functions (linear system of ODEs)

Tags: differential-equations, functions

I am trying to save the output of system of ODE's as functions but I am not getting the time dependence. Also, I am trying to conjugate those expressions but it is also not working. Can anyone please help?

````
In[1]:= 
eq1 = {y1'[t] == (I*a*y1[t]) + (I*e^(I*(ke + ks))*b*y2[t]),  y1[0] == 1};
eq2 = {y2'[t] == (-I*c*y2[t]) + (I*e^(-I*(ke + ks))*d*y1[t]), y2[0] == 0};
sol = FullSimplify[DSolve[{eq1, eq2}, {y1[t], y2[t]}, t]];
y1t = FullSimplify[y1[t] /. sol][[1]]
y2t = FullSimplify[y2[t] /. sol][[1]]

Out[4]= 
(E^(1/2 I (a - c) t) (Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]
     Cos[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t] + 
   I (a + c) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t]))/Sqrt[(a + c)^2 +  4 b d]

Out[5]= 
(2 I d e^(-I (ke + ks)) E^(1/2 I (a - c) t)
  Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t])/Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]

In[30]:= 
f = Conjugate[y1t];
Simplify[f, {a, b, c, d, t} \[Element] Reals]

Out[31]= 
E^(-(1/2) I (a - c) t)
  Conjugate[ Cos[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t] + (
   I (a + c) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t])/
   Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]] ```
````

Comment: In `eq1` and `eq2`, does `e` stand for the Euler Number while writing  `I*e^(I*(ke + ks))...` ? and the `I` stands for $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: Exactly yes. Thank you.

Comment: Mathematica uses `E` or you can use the  `Exp[...]` function. Please look at the first symbol in`Out[4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" )*

Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = {y1'[t] == (I*a*y1[t]) + (I*E^(I*(ke + ks))*b*y2[t]), y1[0] == 1};
eq2 = {y2'[t] == (-I*c*y2[t]) + (I*E^(-I*(ke + ks))*d*y1[t]), y2[0] == 0};

sol = DSolve[{eq1, eq2}, {y1[t], y2[t]}, t] // FullSimplify;

y1t[t_] = y1[t] /. sol[[1]]

(* (E^(1/2 I (a - c) t) (Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]
       Cos[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t] + 
     I (a + c) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t]))/(Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]) *)

y2t[t_] = y2[t] /. sol[[1]]

(* (2 I d E^(-(1/2) I (2 ke + 2 ks + (-a + c) t))
  Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t])/Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] *)

f[t_] = Simplify[Conjugate[y1t[t]], {a, b, c, d, t} ∈ Reals]

(* E^(-(1/2) I (a - c) t)
  Conjugate[
  Cos[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t] + (
   I (a + c) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t])/Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]] *)
```

To eliminate the [`Conjugate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate.html) use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
f = Conjugate[y1t[t]] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] & // 
  FullSimplify

(* (E^(1/2 I (-a + c) t) (Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]
       Cos[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t] - 
     I (a + c) Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d] t]))/(Sqrt[(a + c)^2 + 4 b d]) *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bob Hanlon. Could you tell me what is happening exactly. It works like a charm but I don't quite understand why..

Comment: As stated in the documentation, "ComplexExpand[expr] expands expr assuming that all variables are real." and `ComplexExpand` knows that the conjugate of a real number is just the number itself. Alternatively, explicitly assume that all variables are real when simplifying after taking the conjugate.